# Which preposition with "compensate"?

Tags: prepositions, phrasal-verbs

> "The good quality can't compensate for the high price."
>   "Its high price can't be compensated with good quality."
>   "Its high price can't be compensated by good quality."
>   "Its high price can't be compensated for by good quality."
>   "Its high price can't be compensated for with good quality."

I am mostly confused whether this verb takes "for" or not especially in the 4th and 5th examples. (I can't edit the question myself doesn't work on phone)

Comment: can't be compensated *for*...   To compensate, and to compensate for, have different meanings.

Comment: what are those meanings? To me its to "equalize something" in all 3,

Comment: Someone can *compensate* you for work you have performed, that is, pay you.  A young footballer, say, might *compensate for* being slightly underweight and below average in height by developing excellent foot skills and speed.

Comment: Did I split the fourth example correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Compensate with" is the instrumental form:  someone is using something as a compensatory agent.

"Compensate for" refers to the shortcoming for which compensation is needed.

Your example, slightly rephrased: "Its high quality cannot compensate for its high price".  Or "Its high price cannot be compensated [for] by its high quality".  The "for" in the second form is more US than Commonwealth usage.